# Form based authentication is not redirecting to login page

Tags: java, tomcat, form-authentication

I am using Form-based authentication in web.xml in Tomcat.

```
<login-config> 
<auth-method>FORM</auth-method> 
<realm-name>Example Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name> 
<form-login-config> 
<form-login-page>/LoginServlet</form-login-page> 
<form-error-page>/LoginServlet</form-error-page> 
</form-login-config> 
</login-config>
```

In my WebApp I have a page "Action.jsp" and a filter (MyFilter.java). I am printing the value of username and session Id in MyFilter. When the session times out, the page action.jsp is opened and in filter log it showing username as null. But it does not redirect to login page. 
What could be the problem?

LoginServlet simply redirects to login page.

```
 response.sendRedirect(response
              .encodeRedirectURL("/WebFwCore/web/pages/main.jsp"));
```

and in filter I am printing

```
 request.getRemoteUser();
    request.isUserInRole('something');
```

which is coming null
and in web.xml

```
               <web-resource-name>View pages</web-resource-name>
                        <url-pattern>/jsp/ann/ann_main.jsp</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/jsp/ann/ann_tcu.jsp</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/jsp/ann/import_ann_files.jsp</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/jsp/dtmf/dtmf.jsp</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/jsp/languagetah/languagetag.jsp</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/jsp/languagetah/action.jsp</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/jsp/languagetah/languagetag_load_result.jsp</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/jsp/languagetah/languagetag_load_error_detail.jsp</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/jsp/tone/tone.jsp</url-pattern>
                </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>fsNetworkingView</role-name>
                <role-name>fsNetworkingManage</role-name>
                <role-name>fsWebUIAllowAll</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
```

Comment: what is your session checking code? and auth checking code in `LoginServlet`

Comment: how the session is bound with request? user can logon with new request for which session is timedout!!

Comment: @TechExchange Please see my comment to below post. I am not using filter to invalidate session. Just for a check I used a filter there.

Comment: you are trying to pring a value from session which is non-existing, but the user role is existing in `request` - find a way to bind request with session nor simply put a check

Comment: ok filter is used just to confirm that the session is invalid. by getting the user name which is coming null.. It does not serve anything else. Even if I remove filter, it is opening the page but user would be null. Rather it should have redirected to /loginServlet. which happens with other pages of application. but only this page I am stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

In LoginServlet

- check for the session from the `Request` using `request.getSession(false);`
- if session is null, redirect to loginpage
- Always check for the session before examining the request, because requests can be fresh (along with auth) but earlier request to which session is bounded might have expired
- Or , you can use a session listener to caputre session expiry and act appropriately as app demands.

Comment: but shouldn't form based authentication should take care of this already. If the session expires it will automatically redirect to the page specified in  <form-login-page>/LoginServlet</form-login-page>. And it is working for all other pages fine. if I try to open a different page from same WebApp it is redirecting to loginServlet.  But only in one page.

Comment: is user in role - 'Yes' , do you remember his existing session - 'Nah'

Comment: sorry could not follow you .. :(